# Trying to get Tableau parameter to recognize filters applied

Tags: filter, parameters, tableau-desktop

I have a dashboard with two worksheets.  One of the worksheets is a bar chart with just one dimension, Model Name.  I've added a Top N parameter to it, set to display only the Top N highest priced items.

The other worksheet is a bar chart at a higher category level, and I'm using that as a filter for the other.  So when I click on one of the categories, the other worksheet should display the Top N items for that category.  But, when I click on a category, the other bar chart goes blank.  My thinking is that the parameter is applying to the entire dataset, and not recognizing the filters applied.

I've tried changing the filters to context, but that hasn't rectified the situation. Is there a way that I can get the parameter to recognize the active filters?

Comment: if the first filter is applied, it reduces the scope of the second "parameter-controlled" filter. if you want me to take a closer look, you can share a dummy workbook on Tableau public

Answer (score 0):

If you want the filter to be evaluated first, you can do that by right-clicking on the filter item and select "Add to context."
[image: add filter to context]

For more, see Tableau's "[Use Context Filters](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_context.htm)".